# asp.net gridview with drop down , text box and checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In a user contorl I need to have a asp.net grid view with dropdown,text box and checkboxes , whose values may be mapped from database if it exist or it will be 
loaded as a default control. Then once user makes it seclection I need to save 
the selected values in databse.[image]

see the message below. This is how the grid view needs to look like:
Does any one have an example of some thing similar implemented???

Comment: You should try something, if faced problem, then you can ask specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a button outside the grid that says "Save" onclick it loops in a foreach gridview row and gets the value of each dropdown, textbox, checkbox and saves to the database.

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in gvMyGrid.Rows)
{
    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddl1");
    //code here to save this value
}
```

something like that, i use it all the time and works like a charm.

there's also a way to postback from any control in your grid and do something with it, check it out, [adsanti.wordpress.com](https://adsanti.wordpress.com/2011/07/19/gridview-dropdownlist-postback-to-load-info/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [Editable Gridview with Textbox, CheckBox, Radio Button and DropDown List](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37207/Editable-Gridview-with-Textbox-CheckBox-Radio-Butt)